# Unable to render the values in drop down list

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON text and three dropdown lists.

First dropdown list will be populating Entities `(Applicant, Person, Plan)`.
Second dropdown list will be populating Association Types of selected Entity from previous selection.

```
(Here ‘Person’ and ‘Plan’ will be rendered by selecting “Applicant” as Entity)
```

The third dropdown list should populate the Attribute values. (Based on selection of Association Type from the second dropdown list, it should display the attributes of respective Entity)

Example: If I select `Person` Association type in 2nd dropdown list then Attributes of Person Entity has to be displayed.

I have tried solving this problem.

I could get the values for the first two dropdown lists. I have tried rendering the values however I am facing some problems.

Can someone help me how to get the values??

http://jsbin.com/toqisibumo/edit?html,js,output

If you dont understand question, Please dont hesitate to ask. Thanks

Comment: Your http request is not working. Getting this error :  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solve your issue.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select ng-model="dd1" ng-options="item.Entity for item in data">
  </select>

  <select ng-model="dd2" ng-options="ass.associationType for ass in dd1.Associations" ng-change="loadDD3()"> 
  </select>

  <select ng-model="dd3" ng-options="atr.name for atr in dataDD3">
  </select>

</body>
<script>
    var angular = angular.module('myApp', []);

    angular.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

        $scope.data = [
            {
                "Attributes":[
                    {"name":"CSRPercent","attributeType":"decimal"},
                    {"name":"date","attributeType":"date"},
                    {"name":"hoursPerWeek","attributeType":"long"},
                    {"name":"householdSize","attributeType":"long"},
                    {"name":"income","attributeType":"decimal"},
                    {"name":"incomePeriod","attributeType":"string"},
                    {"name":"isEligibleForCostSharingReduction","attributeType":"boolean"},
                    {"name":"isEligibleForIncomeBasedMedi_CAL","attributeType":"boolean"},
                    {"name":"isEligibleForMedi_Cal_Access","attributeType":"boolean"},
                    {"name":"isEligibleForPremiumAssistance","attributeType":"boolean"},
                    {"name":"state","attributeType":"string"},
                    {"name":"zip","attributeType":"string"}
                ],
                "Associations":[
                    {"associationType":"Person","name":"familyMembers"},
                    {"associationType":"Plan","name":"plans"}
                ],
                "Entity":"Applicant"
            },
            {
                "Attributes":[
                    {"name":"age","attributeType":"long"},
                    {"name":"isPregnant","attributeType":"boolean"}
                ],
                "Entity":"Person"
            },
            {
                "Attributes":[
                    {"name":"company","attributeType":"string"},
                    {"name":"costPerPerson","attributeType":"decimal"},
                    {"name":"name","attributeType":"string"},
                    {"name":"premiumAssistance","attributeType":"decimal"},
                    {"name":"stars","attributeType":"long"},
                    {"name":"totalMonthlyPremium","attributeType":"decimal"},
                    {"name":"yourMonthlyPremium","attributeType":"decimal"}
                ],
                "Entity":"Plan"
            }
        ];

        $scope.dataDD2 = [];
        $scope.loadDD3=function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
                var obj = $scope.data[i];
                if(obj.Entity == $scope.dd2.associationType)
                {
                    $scope.dataDD3 = obj.Attributes;
                }
            }           
        };

    });
</script>
</html>
```

But still I have some issues.

For the dropdown1 you have three values(Applicant, Person, Plan).

If you select Applicant you will load Associations(Person, Plan) to the dropdown2.

What if you select either Person or Plan in dropdown1 ?
For those two you don't have associations ryt.

Comment: Hi Nifal Nizar , your solution is working fine. However, If i select Person or Plan from 1st dropdown list  , the 2nd and 3rd dropdown lists should be disabled.

Comment: Hi Nifal, I have modified the code. Please check the same. http://jsbin.com/qojijozafe/edit?html,js,output . Here I can disable the 3rd dropdown list however previously selected value is selected and disabled state . Can you see this one.

Comment: write a condition and change the $scope.dataDD3 = [];

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we can't test your jsbin, because the get request fails (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)

Secondly, I see this line of code:

```
<select ng-model="z" ng-change="addAttributes()" ng-options="sel.name for sel in z.Attributes">
```

You've set the ng-model to `'z'`, and then try to get the options from `'z.Attribute'`, but your `'z' model` is not populated with anything. Maybe you wanted to make `y.Attributes` ?

UPDATE:

I think you are having troubles with your JSON data.
here's an [updated link](http://jsbin.com/qoceruyafa/1/edit?html,js,output).
Select **Applicant -> Person -> FamilyMembers**

is this the behaviour you want?

If so, look how I've modified your select:

```
<select ng-model="z" ng-change="addAttributes()" ng-options="color.name for color in y.names">
```

and this is how I've modified your JSON data:

```
...
"Associations":[{"associationType":"Person","names":[{"name" : "familyMembers"}]}
...
```

so names is an array containing your values.

Comment: You are correct but y.Attributes doesn's give anything as the association type doesn't have  attributes. Only Entities have.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your codes.
In the third drop-down your loading the data from

> sel.name for sel in z.Attributes

Where it has to be

> sel.name for sel in x.Attributes

Then you will get the dropdown

Comment: In his requirement, he says:

"The third dropdown list should populate the Attribute values. (Based on selection of Association Type from the second dropdown list, it should display the attributes of respective Entity)"

but with your code, 3rd dropdown doesn't depend on 2nd.

Comment: @Nifal Nizar, Thanks for your answer. My requirement is what Arthur has commented.

Comment: I was trying to compare the selected value from the 2nd dropdown list with the entities and assigning the entity to some model variable and then trying to get the values.

Comment: @Balu, have you checked my updated answer, is that what you want?

Comment: Hi Arthur, I have checked your answer. You were displaying the name of association Type. I need to render the attributes of Person Entity. 

If I select Person from 2nd dropdown, the 3rd dropdown should list age,isPregnant values.
If I select planes from 2nd dropdown list, the 3rd dropdown list should list company,costPerPerson,name,stars etc…

Comment: Arrthur, FYI, I will be getting the JSON data from external server. I should not modify the input.